# laravel 5.2 delete file button

Tags: laravel, delete-file

I have a Laravel 5.2 website with multiple file uploads. I have a file delete button that is not working. User is just redirected back to the page but the file is still there.

show.blade

```
 <div class="row">
                                    <form class="col-xs-2" method="POST" action="/exception/{{$truckingDelivery->exception->id}}">

                                        {!! csrf_field() !!}

                                        <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">

                                        <button type="submit" class="fa fa-times pull-left" id="deleteFileButton"></button>
                                    </form>

                                    <a class="col-xs-10" href="{{$truckingDelivery->exception->path}}" target="_blank">View Exception</a>
                                </div>
```

routes.php

```
Route::delete('/exception/{id}','TruckingDeliveryController@deleteException');
```

Exception Model

```
 public function delete(){

    \File::delete([

        $this->path,

        $this->name

    ]);

    parent::delete();
}
```

Trucking Delivery Model

```
public function exception()
{

    return $this->hasOne('App\Exception', 'trucking_delivery_id');
}
```

Trucking Delivery Controller

```
public function deleteException($id){

    $exception = Exception::findOrFail($id)->delete();

    return back();    

}
```

Answer (score 0):

destroy is correct method for removing an entity directly (via object or model).

```
 public function deleteException($id){

   $exception = Exception::destroy($id);

   return back();    

}
```

Comment: delete() function is being called in model. This method works for all other uploads on my website.

Comment: Im wondering if     protected static function boot(){ } in my Exception model is affecting this? Won't show on the page without it.

Comment: did you get the id value in deleteException method.

Comment: yes, the id is showing in the form action in the view